Raspbian OS / Klipper Box Only SSH need Wlan1 to work how to?
I setup a raspbian os with klipperbox and mainsailos its for my 3d printer. all works well but my rpi 3b has less connection to wlan with the build in setup. so i put in a usb wlan fritzbox n v2 its old but should work i think. Now i want to setup that the USB Wlan is used and not the build in. but i cant find a tutorial how to do
Bus 001 Device 039: ID 057c:8501 AVM GmbH FRITZ WLAN N v2 [RT5572/rt2870.bin]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First think about to upgrade to "Raspberry Pi OS" as Raspbian is quite out dated.
And second the is a RealTec chipset so look for a RT5572  driver.
